# How to hide sensitive data like password and given Data table details used in examples in feature file cucumber framework in Extent report?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, bdd, cucumber-java, selenium-extent-report, automation-testing

I need to hide sensitive data like password from extent report to share report to client which is configured with cucumber BDD framework selenium JAVA.
Can anyone please help me is there any way the sensitive data like password and secret from Given data table displayed from extent report is hidden ?

Example:-

```
Feature: User Creation
Scenario Outline: Admin user create new user
Given user enter details
  | name   | email           | secret   |
  | Aslak  | aslak@test.com  | Test123  |
When admin user create new user with "<username>" and "<password>"
Then user should be created

Examples:
| username | password   |
| aman     | Password@1 |
```

Need to hide the password and secret from the extent report while sharing to the team.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to achieve this is, you encode the password in your Given step and decode that in the implemented step or use the way your application stores and decodes the password. Something like this

```
Feature: User Creation

Scenario Outline: Admin user create new user
Given user enter details
    | name  | email          | secret  |
    | Aslak | aslak@test.com | Test123 | 
When admin user create new user with "" and "" Then user should be created

Examples:
| username | password         |
| aman     | 9cc3e5abdfaee198a|
```

Something like this and use a decoding algorithm in your stepdef. If your passwords or MD5 encrypted then pass the encrypted value itself

Answer (score 0):

Consider mapping usernames to passwords in your step definitions, or retrieving them from an environment variable or configuration file.

When moving passwords to configuration, you are free to define different passwords for different environments. Each developer or tester can define their own passwords. Whoever helps maintain the build servers can define the passwords for the continuous integration environment.

The password is not important information from a behavioral driven development perspective, so omit this from the scenarios.